# How to scale a plane to the exact dimensions of a loop cut?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I have a plane and a loop cut that is highlighted as shown in the image above. I wanted to know how do I scale the plane to the exact dimensions of the loop cut?

Answer (score 2):

You may do it using a ***snapping tool***. 
First select the edge loop in *Edit Mode* (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd>) and snap the cursor to it (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>-->*Cursor to Selected*). Then select the plane in *Object Mode* and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>-->*Selection to Cursor [Offset]*).
[image]

Next press the *magnet icon* to enable the *snapping tool* and change its type to *Vertex*. Scale the plane until it snaps to the loopcut's border. 
[image]

To see the loopcut in *Object Mode* check the *Wire* and *Draw All Edges* checkboxes in *Display* panel of the *Object* header.
[image]

For irregular planes you can scale along the chosen axes (e.g. <kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>Y</kbd>).
[image]

You may also snap the plane to the corner of the edge loop in *Object Mode*. Then change the *pivot point* type to *3D Cursor*, snap the cursor to the corner of the plane in *Edit Mode* with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>-->*Cursor to Selected* and then scale it until it fits the edgeloop.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply select the loop. Duplicate it. Then fill the duplicate (f key). Check your normals to make sure they are going the right direction.